# kafka consumer to store history of events in a data store

Tags: apache-kafka

We are working with kafka as Event Streaming Platform. So far, there is one producer of data and 3 consumers, each of them subcribed to one or several topics in kafka. This is working perfectly fine. Fyi, the kafka retention period is set to 5s since we don't need to persist the events more than that.

Right now, we have a new use-case coming to persist all the events for the latest 20 mins (in an another data store) for post-analysis (mainly for training purposes). So this new kafka consumer should subscribe to all existing topics. We only want to persist the history of latest 20mins of events in the data store and not all the events for a session (that can represent several hours or days). TThe targetted througput is 170kb/s and for 20mins it is almost 1M of messages to be persisted.

We are wondering which architecture pattern is adapted for such situtation? This is not a nominal use-case compared to the current use-cases, so we don't want to reduce the performance of the system to be able to manage it. Our idea is to empty the topcis as fast as we can , push the data into a queue and have another app with a different rate in charge of reading the data from the queue and persisting them into the store.

We woul greatly appreciate any experience or feedback to manage such use-case. Especially about the expiration/pruge mechanism to be used. For sure we need something highly available and scalable.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use Kafka Connect with `topics.regex=*` to consume everything and write to one location, but you'll end up with a really high total lag, especially if you keep adding new topics.

If you have `retention.ms=5000`, then I don't know if Kafka is a proper tool for your use case, but perhaps you could ingest into Splunk or Elasticsearch or other time-series system where you can properly slice by 20 minute windows.